# How to pass binary data from C++ to Node.js

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

I have a binary data in c++ variable buffer as below:

```
int len = 39767;
uint16_t * buffer = (uint16_t) malloc(len);
FILE * fp = fopen("rahul.jpg", "rb"); // size of file is 39767 byte.
fread(buffer, len, 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
fp = fopen("rahul3.jpg", "wb");
fwrite(buffer, len, 1, fp);  // Here it is written correct.
fclose(fp);
```

I want to pass this buffer to Node.js and write to a file. I used below line to convert it to Local and then wrapping to an Object:

```
Local<String> str = Nan::New(buffer).ToLocalChecked();
return scope.Escape(str);
```

But, in node.js when I am checking length of received data it prints 9 only and value seems corrupted.

```
console.log(data);
console.log("len = " + data.length );
fs.writeFileSync('rahul2.jpg', data, 'binary');
```

Here rahul2.jpg is corrupted and is of 9 bytes only. How can we get rahul2.jpg from node.js code same as rahul.jpg in c++? Which Nan::New() we should use to pass binary data unaffected? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose, `ToLocalChecked()` provide a string, and some conversion of data is performed. So consider posibilities of data specification for `New` or use other method insted this

Comment: Try `Nan::NewBuffer()`

Comment: After applying CopyBuffer(), I can see data in node.js as <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46> of 10 bytes only. How can I get rahul2.jpg same as rahul.jpg? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
   Local<Value> returnValue = Nan::CopyBuffer(buffer, len).ToLocalChecked();
```

and, by the way, `fread` returns the number of bytes read from file, so it is better to do as follows:

```
   int truelen = fread(buffer, len, 1, fp);
   . . .
   fwrite(buffer, truelen, 1, fp);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But, still unable to get full data in node.js. My console.log is printing below data and rahul2.jpg has only 9 bytes.
```<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46>
len = 10```

Comment: No. I am using fs.writeFileSync(). I don't have any fd to close.

Comment: Thanks @VolAnd . CopyBuffer() and NewBuffer() returns Local<Value> and updating code has worked.

Answer (score 0):

`Local<String> str = Nan::NewOneByteString((uint8_t *) buffer, len).ToLocalChecked();`

I used above code in C++ which solved the issue. In node.js used the below code to write to file:
`fs.writeFileSync('rahul2.jpg', data, 'binary');`

Thanks.